# AWS VPC - Logical isolation from other virtual networks

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, vpc, cidr

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/how-it-works.html) says, "A virtual private cloud (VPC) is a virtual network dedicated to your AWS account. It is logically isolated from other virtual networks in the AWS Cloud."

My understanding is, reason, my VPC is isolated from other virtual network
is due to **CIDR** notation(network `1xx.xx.0.0/16`) assigned to VPC.

[image]
So, if the CIDR notation for my VPC is `10.10.0.0/16` then this CIDR notation(`10.10.0.0/16`) is not being used in other virtual networks of AWS cloud.

---

Private IPv4 range

```
10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255
```

---

1) Is AWS cloud a big private network? with each VPC assigned a CIDR from private IP space. If AWS cloud is a private network, then, can we assign public IP to a resource within private network?

[image]

2) 
Is it CIDR parameter, that allows isolation of my VPC from other virtual networks in AWS cloud?

3) Does AWS cloud have overlapping IP domain? Across AWS vpc

Comment: Read up on RFC 1918 and private networks.

Comment: 1. of course they are addressing in private ranges.. they dont allocate public ips internaly 2. forget about cidr... your vpc is just like an island, decoupled from other scope... internaly, maybe islands have the same ip and they distinguish islands with other techologies

Comment: @tgyger Wrt first point... I see public IP assigned to EC2 right? I can see that on AWS console in EC2 dashboard... I see public DNS name & public IP... in addition to private IP

Comment: yes they do... but, is your endsystem really addressed with an public ip? ;-) you can buy one, and its allocated to your virtual device... there are plenty of implementation variants

Comment: @tgyger Query edited for your first point.. ELB is also assgned public IP

Comment: there are 2 options to point a public ip to your system. 1. the sytem is addressed with a public ip. 2. public ip is translated to a private ip. i don't know how aws is doing it, i think its the second one.

Comment: but hey!! don't care about ip addressing on aws... focus on the service you need :-)

Comment: The public IP address is mapped to the primary private IP address through network address translation (NAT). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

Comment: @overexchange... you can read all about ip addressing in the link above... as i said, they are translating it.. have a good time on ec2 :-)

Comment: @tgyger so... `ip a` command in ec2 does not list  public IP ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202390/discussion-between-tgyger-and-overexchange).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CIDR

From the early birth of IP, addressing was stiched to a classfull behaviour. what does this mean.... a Routers maximum prefix for a class A network was 10.0.0.0 /8 (10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255) for a class B Network it was 172.26.0.0 (172.26.0.0 - 172.26.255.255). This is called classfull addressing "RFC 791". But hey, what if i want to subdivide those ranges and have one subnet in USA and the other in europe. There comes CIDR (CLASSLESS interdomain routing ) into the game. Since CIDR RFCs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) we are not stiched to that Classfull restriction anymore. Now, we are free to subdivide as we want (variable length subnetmasking or VLSM)

## AWS

on AWS you can have a VPC which is a VirtualPrivateCloud. Its a isolated construct with its own virtual Router and its own private (not Public!!) IP-Range (a CIDR Range). It is completely isolatet from everything... like you would install a switch, router and computers in your bedroom. You can Subdivide your VPC in smaller portitions (availability Zones). Then you'll make a nonoverlapping ip addressing, lets say, AZ1=10.0.1.0/24, AZ2=10.0.2.0/24, AZ3=10.0.3.0/24. With your router in the bedroom... aahh sorry, VPC, you are interconnecting those Zones together. lets say AZ1=Web, AZ2=APP, AZ3=DB... so, how can you bring AZ1 to the Internet? you are placing a Internet-Gateway in front of the VPC. What about public IP now? AWS has 2 scenario. public IP and Elastic public IP... whats the difference? with public IP, the IP is stiched to your instance, not your account. Elastic IP is stiched to your account which means, you can move the public ip between instances in your VPC. Both variants working with NAT (NetworkAddressTranslation)... as you remember, you have a private IP on your instance, so, packets arriving from WWW addressed to your public IP are translated on the Internet-GW to your Private IP. thats it! there are many services like egress-oly gateway (only ipv6), NAT-Gateway (like egress only for ipv4) and so on... you can combine things and build your own logic, but it would blow this thread to explain everything.

one thinig left... you are reaching the Public IP from other VPCs via nat/internet-gateway... but, what if you realy want to interconnect 2 VCPs?? Yes, its possible but, they are not allowed to overlapp CIDR Range!
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html

a good starting point is : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-getting-started.html

to answer your third question:
every Customer (respectively every VPC) can have its own private range which YOU are defining. So, yes, there are overlapping IPs accross the VPCs. The problem beginns there, if you want to join them (VPC peering). the unique identifier between (unjoined) VPCs is the public IP in it, and they are unique! no overlapping between VPCs

i hope that helps a bit

**edit:** of course they are not using physical stuff to create VPCs, they are doing it with virtualized network components (network function virtualisation NFV)